# Proving that the line CR passing through intersection of altitudes AP and BQ is orthogonal to AB

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Picture]

How would you go about solving this?
I've tried using projections to prove CO.AB = 0 but haven't made much progress.

Comment: Do you know the fact that altitudes in a triangle intersect in a single point (orthocenter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Construct a Cartesian coordinate using Q as the origin.

Assume $A(a,0), B(0,b), C(c,0)$

the slope of AB: $ b/(0-a) = -b/a $

the slope of BC: $(0-b)/(c-0) = -b/c$

therefore, because the product of the slope of the altitude and the slope of side is $-1$, the slope of the BC side's altitude (i.e. AP): $c/b$

the linear equation of AP: $y = \frac{c}{b} (x-a)$

the y-component of intersection of altitudes AP and BQ: let $x = 0$ in AP's equation

=> $y = -\frac{ac}{b} $

So the coordinate of intersection is $(0,-\frac{ac}{b})$ denote the intersection as point G.

the slope of GC: $(-\frac{ac}{b}-0)/(0-c) = \frac{a}{b} $

Since the product of the slope of GC and the slope of AB is $-1$,

it proves that they are orthogonal.

Cites:

[Why the product of the slope two perpendicular lines is negative one](https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=slope+of+two+orthogonal+lines)